# Cleanup/Refactor Jquery event binding to avoid possible duplication

Tags: jquery, ajax

There's another way to write this code ? I think it's kinda unprofessional and messy

Basically the code submit a form by "Enter key" and mouse "Click" so there's another way ?

```
$("#form-signup-login input#login-submit").click(function()
{
    doLogin();
});
$('input#login-request-username-email, input#login-request-password').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
        doLogin();
});
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Would elaborate on what you find "unprofessional" and "messy" in this code?

Comment: It looks perfectly cromulent to me.

Comment: @JulienBourdon I thought maybe there's a function to do this togheter and not with these 2 functions: click and keyup

Comment: The only thing I would change is that the selector in front of the final `id` selector are unnecessary since `id`s are unique

Comment: Your core function is yet doLogin. As you have a test on the keyup, it's hard to pass the same function as handler in both cases.

Comment: @YiJiang +1 : id must not be prefixed

Comment: You do not need to add "(solved)" to the subject. Just mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#login-submit").click(doLogin);

$('#login-request-password').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13)
        doLogin();
});
```

Explanation:

1. No need to prepend id selectors with containers as they are unique on the page and you will fallback to the native `getElementById` method which is faster than the sizzle engine.
2. You can just use the function pointer in the first case, no need to build another call back function
3. I would just bind the keyup event on the password field rather than the username field as there is a natual flow there

Alternatively bind form submit which takes care of all this by default for you..

```
$("#form-signup-login").submit(doLogin);
```

Comment: that's what I meant. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for the `submit` event handler by any chance? http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to do this on submit: why not use:

```
$("#form-signup-login").on("submit", function() {
    doLogin();
    return false;
});
```

Where the id is the ID of the form, not any of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form-signup-login").submit(function (ev){
  // Do not let the browser handle the submit action
  ev.preventDefault();
  // Execute your custom submit function
  doLogin();
});
```

Voila!